# ClickOnce Application Update Assistance

Tags: c#, wpf, database, xaml, clickonce

I'm creating a desktop application using WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) and ClickOnce, and in the application I compare strings from an uploaded file to strings stored in a database.

I'm not permitted to access the database from the application directly, so I need to store the list of database strings in the application, then update the list anytime changes are made to the database (The whole application would need to be updated each time the database changes).

What would be my best option to implement re-reading the database and updating the list of strings in the application?

Comment: When you say "The whole application would need to be updated", do you mean republished? Or just the data inside updated? If it's just the data inside, would it be an option to expose the data you need from the database via a WebAPI microservice, and query that as needed from your WPF app (or use SignalR to notify your app of changes)? Or, service buses might be another alternative.

Comment: The only thing that needs to be updated is the list of strings in the application.  Basically I need to create something that opens a connection to the database, reads it, and if anything is changed, I read the database into a new list, and update the existing list with the new list, then close the connection.  Once the existing list is updated, I'm assuming I would need to republish or something.  Apparently it's a security issue if the connection is open while the application is running.

Comment: If connection to db is an issue, why don't you make webservice that exposes just the part of db you're interested in (i.e. list of strings) ?